# Go to specific view controller in UIPageViewController with UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I currently have a UITabBarController with two tabs, one of which leads to a storyboard that has several view controllers within it. The problem occurs when I traverse away from the storyboard tab and then come back to it and I find myself at the view controller that I left off. How can I ensure that every time I come back to the tab with the storyboard, I start at the initial view controller?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Swift:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if(tabBarController?.selectedIndex == 1){   //The second tab index
        tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, however I don't think the selectedIndex property tells the UITabBarController which view controller to direct to _within_ a certain tab. I think instead it tells the UITabBarController which tab to direct to. Is that correct?

Comment: I was trying to make it so that when a tab is selected, then the user is directed to a specific view controller in that tab. I solved the problem by instantiating the entire storyboard within viewWillAppear because that gets called every time the view appears, whereas viewDidLoad gets called once.